# Can't get an entire HTML with python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping

```
import urllib.request    
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent':' Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36'}
url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/KO/history?period1=-252374400&period2=1595116800&interval=1mo&filter=history&frequency=1mo'

req  = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
html = resp.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
data = soup.find_all("tr", {'class':'BdT Bdc($seperatorColor) Ta(end) Fz(s) Whs(nw)'})
data = [x.get_text("|") for x in data]
```

When I go through what it finds, it only finds the first 75 instances of that tag and ignores the rest. How do I get more than 75 instances?

Comment: You will have to provide an URL for us to be able to help you.What have you done so far to understand why you're only getting the first 75 instances ?

Comment: For Yahoo finance for instance... https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/KO/history?period1=-252374400&period2=1595116800&interval=1mo&filter=history&frequency=1mo

Comment: This is because it's using infinite scroll to get new data after 75 rows. Infinite scroll is javascript driven mechanism to make new data appear on the site. It uses HTTP requests to display data. So you need mimic those requests to get new rows of data. Also are you providing your complete code ? because the code above doesnt to work for me.

Comment: I updated the post with the exact code